# Polymer nested app routes are not mapping correctly

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to get some basic routes right. I'm using Polymer 1.5.0 and I'm having problems using nested routes.

I'm using app-route 0.9.2

As [this post suggests](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/routing), Polymer uses a decentralized approach in routing. Therefore I decided to do the following:

```
<app-route route="{{route}}"
       pattern="/:page"
       data="{{data}}"
       tail="{{tail}}">
</app-route>

  <iron-pages selected="{{data.page}}" attr-for-selected="title" fallback-selection="404">
      <pgarena-home-app title="" route="{{tail}}" ></pgarena-home-app>
      <pgarena-tournament-app title="tournament" route="{{tail}}"></pgarena-tournament-app>
      <pgarena-account-app title="account" route="{{tail}}"></pgarena-account-app>
      <div title="404">
          <h1>{{data.page}} could not be found!</h1>
      </div>
  </iron-pages>
```

**Subpages:**

pgarena-account-app

```
<iron-pages selected="{{data.action}}" attr-for-selected="title" fallback-selection="404">
            <pgarena-account-index-view title=""></pgarena-account-index-view>
            <pgarena-account-login-view title="login"></pgarena-account-login-view>
            <pgarena-account-register-view title="register"></pgarena-account-register-view>
            <div title="404">
                <h1>Not found :(</h1>
            </div>
        </iron-pages>
```

pgarena-tournament-app

```
<!-- Chooses the new tournament page. -->
      <app-route 
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:action"
        data="{{data}}"
        tail="{{tail}}"
        >
        </app-route>

    <iron-pages selected="{{data.action}}" attr-for-selected="title" fallback-selection="404">
        <pgarena-tournament-index-view title=""></pgarena-tournament-index-view>    
        <!-- The list of all the tournaments -->    
        <pgarena-tournament-list-view title="list"></pgarena-tournament-list-view>
        <div title="404">
            <h1>Not Found!</h1>
        </div>
    </iron-pages>
```

Everything seems ok, right? According to the URL  What I'm doing here is taking advantage of Lazy Load of elements.

I've seen in the [Polycasts examples](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/tree/master/ep47-app-route-fouc/blog) that they use the "hidden" approach. In which they select the element. The problem is that we lose the "Lazy Loading Advantage".

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG! I totally forgot. [In Polycasts #46/47](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAgSvlYavX0) Rob Dodson makes the **strong emphasis** that when using iron-selector, we should pass **one-way binding** which is with the square brackets `[]` versus the curly brackets `{}`

So at the end of the day **it should have been**:

```
<iron-pages selected="[[data.action]]"
```

Instead of:

```
<iron-pages selected="{{data.action}}"
```