# Polymer routing: inner routes not reflecting

Tags: routes, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am very new to `Polymer` and have been reading up and trying out a few things to get some hands-on experience.

I decided to have Polymer as the views platform to a `NodeJS` (with `ExpressJS` as middleware) driven app that will serve out some media like videos, music and pictures. Incidentally, i am also new to NodeJS and Express but i have it working well enough to serve up to my Polymer views.

I am having some issues with having inner routes reflect. The address bar reflects the URL but my view does not change accordingly. I seem to be missing something basic.

I have the following flow:

- App is served from a "nodepolymer" directory in my webserver (i.e. it is not a root app)
  Example URL: `mywebroot/nodepolymer`
- The homepage will have some selected pictures/text of available media. Links to Videos/Music and Pictures will take the user to individual landing pages that will serve up a list of all available media of the selected type/category.
  Example URL: `mywebroot/nodepolymer/view-videos` or `mywebroot/nodepolymer/view-music` etc etc
- Clicking on a particular media file will open into its own individual page
  Example URL: `mywebroot/nodepolymer/view-music/view-media` (no media identifier in the URL but the 'view-media' will be common across categories)
- Might go even one further level further (i understand the nesting is deep already but i may have the need) and have a page/view that serves as a function-only view. Example URL: `mywebroot/view-pictures/view-media/create-meme` or `mywebroot/view-videos/view-media/extract-audio` etc etc.

The root route and the first-level works fine i.e the urls like `mywebroot/view-videos/` or `mywebroot/view-music/`. The inner levels like `mywebroot/view-videos/view-media` does reflect in the address bar but the view does not switch. It shows the `mywebroot/view-videos/` view.

The relevant files/code for getting the basic routing working are listed below. I am using the latest versions of Polymer and the route is handled by `app-route` (app-route#^0.9.2). Thanks in for any pointers.

My index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
<title>My App</title>
<meta name="description" content="My App description">
<link rel="icon" href="/nodepolymer/images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="manifest" href="/nodepolymer/manifest.json">
<script>
    window.Polymer = {
        dom: 'shadow',
        lazyRegister: true
    };
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        var onload = function() {
            if (!window.HTMLImports) {
                document.dispatchEvent(
                    new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {
                        bubbles: true
                    })
                );
            }
        };
        var webComponentsSupported = (
            'registerElement' in document &&
            'import' in document.createElement('link') &&
            'content' in document.createElement('template')
        );
        if (!webComponentsSupported) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.async = true;
            script.src = '/nodepolymer/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
            script.onload = onload;
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        } else {
            onload();
        }
    })();
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/nodepolymer/service-worker.js');
        });
    }
</script>
<link rel="import" href="/nodepolymer/src/my-app.html">
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

The "my-app" element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="view-videos.html">
<link rel="import" href="view-music.html">
<link rel="import" href="view-home.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-icons.html">
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template id="app">
    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/nodepolymer/:page" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{tail}}"></app-route>
    <iron-pages selected="[[routeData.page]]" attr-for-selected="data-route" fallback-selection="404">
        <section data-route="">
            Home {{routeData.page}}, [[routeData.page]] <!-- To view values on screen, no values displayed on homepage-->
            </br>
            <a href="/nodepolymer/view-videos">View Videos.</a> | <a href="/nodepolymer/view-music">View Music.</a>
            <view-home data-route="view-home" route=""></view-home>
        </section>
        <view-videos data-route="view-videos" route="{{tail}}"></view-videos>
        <view-music data-route="view-music" route="{{tail}}"></view-music>
        <section data-route="404">
            Oops you hit a 404.
            <a href="/nodepolymer">Head back home.</a>
        </section>
    </iron-pages>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-app',
        properties: {
            page: {
                type: String,
                reflectToAttribute: true,
                observer: '_pageChanged'
            }
        },
        observers: [
            '_routeChanged(route.*)',
            '_viewChanged(routeData.view)'
        ],
        _routeChanged: function(changeRecord) {
            console.log("changeRecord: " + JSON.stringify(changeRecord))
            if (changeRecord.path === 'path') {
                console.log('Path changed!');
            }
        },
        _viewChanged: function(view) {
            console.log("View Changed: " + view)
                // load data for view
        },
        _showPage404: function() {
            this.page = 'view404';
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The "view-video" element:

```
<link rel="import" href="view-media.html"> 
<dom-module id="view-videos">
  <template id="app">
    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:vid" data="{{videoData}}" tail="{{subRoute}}"></app-route>
    <app-route route="{{subRoute}}" pattern="/:category" data="{{category}}" tail="{{subRoutes}}"></app-route>
    <app-route route="{{subRoutes}}" pattern="/:cat" data="{{cat}}" tail="{{subRout}}"></app-route>
    <iron-pages selected="[[videoData.vid]]" attr-for-selected="data-route" fallback-selection="404">
        <section data-route="{{videoData.vid}}">
            View Videos {{videoData.vid}}, [[videoData.vid]] ; {{category.category}}, [[category.category]] ; {{cat.cat}}, [[cat.cat]]
            <!--  displays the following text on the view-videos url: nodepolymer, nodepolymer ; view-videos, view-videos ; ,   -->
            <br />
            <a href="/nodepolymer">Home.</a> | <a href="/nodepolymer/view-videos/view-media">View Info for Media.</a>
            <!-- This link will actually be in a repeater and will display a standalone view of the media that is tapped(by passing on an identifier. For testing the routes i have it a simple link. I may later also have another level as "view-video/view-media/my-media-id" for some furhther functions related to the particular media reference). Unable to get this viw intercepted as it defaults to "view-videos" rather than "view-videos/view-media". The URL changes but i see information from "view-video" rather than from "view-media" -->
        </section>
        <view-media data-route="view-media" route="{{subRoute}}"></view-media>
        <section data-route="404">
            404
            <a href="/nodepolymer">Head back home.</a>
        </section>
    </iron-pages>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'view-videos',
        properties: {
            page: {
                type: String,
                reflectToAttribute: true,
                observer: '_pageChanged'
            }
        },
        observers: [
            '_routeChanged(route.*)',
            '_viewChanged(routeData.view)'
        ],
        _routeChanged: function(changeRecord) {
            console.log("changeRecord: " + JSON.stringify(changeRecord))
            if (changeRecord.path === 'path') {
                console.log('Path changed!');
            }
        },
        _viewChanged: function(view) {
            console.log("View Changed: " + view)
                // load data for view
        },
        _showPage404: function() {
            this.page = 'view404';
        }
    });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

The "view-media" element:

```
<dom-module id="view-media">
<template id="appbb">
    <app-location route="{{rout}}"></app-location>
    <app-route route="{{rout}}" pattern="/:pg" data="{{rouData}}" tail="{{tal}}"></app-route>
    <iron-pages selected="[[rouData.pg]]" attr-for-selected="data-route" fallback-selection="404">
        <section data-route="">
            View Media {{rouData.page}}, [[rouData.pg]] <!-- Displays the following data (but view does not switch): nodepolymer, nodepolymer ; view-videos, view-videos ; view-media, view-media  -->
            <a href="/nodepolymer/view-videos">View Videos.</a><br />
            <a href="/nodepolymer/view-music">View Music.</a>
        </section>
        <section data-route="404">
            Oops you hit a 404.
            <a href="/nodepolymer">Head back home.</a>
        </section>
    </iron-pages>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'view-media',
        properties: {
        },
        observers: [
        ],
        _routeChanged: function(changeRecord) {
         },

        _viewChanged: function(view) {
         },
        _showPage404: function() {
            this.page = 'view404';
        }
    });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to find a solution. I went through the documentation and the videos on routes all over again and found that i would need to restructure my app a bit. I did that and I am now able to get several nested levels going.  One immediate issue was that i seemed to have `<app-location>` defined all over. I am now defining it just once. But a clearer structure was the main requirement.

Some useful links(besides the official documentation and videos) for people beginning out on routes in Polymer:

- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622697/polymer-nested-app-routes-are-not-mapping-correctly) (and answer, which has links to a video tutorial).
- This [in-depth write-up](https://timvdlippe.github.io/blog/#/b1-carbon-route) with practical use-cases